# what is the meaning of 수 in the pattern "Verb Stem + (을/ㄹ) 수 있다/없다"?

Tags: grammar

I just learned this pattern,and I guess 수 is a meaningful word,meaning "ability".
is my assumption wrong? what is its meaning or is it just a grammarical word without real meaning?

Answer (score 1):

수 means your ability to do something, a possibility that something can happen, or ways you can achieve something through. It is like 'can' in English.
I referred to https://ko.dict.naver.com/#/entry/koko/57b987f6990d43c69b3d812ab6818d6a

Examples:
Remittance can be made by cheque or credit card.
송금은 수표로도 할 수 있고 신용카드로도 할 수 있다.

Could you help me a moment?
잠깐 나 좀 도와줄 수 있니?

Comment: 당신의 대답이 때문에 감삽니다

Answer (score 0):

The "수" as in "할 수 있다/없다" was originated from the character "[手](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E6%89%8B)," which means

- a hand,
- a possible case/way (as in, "There's no *way* to do that"),
- a possible move (in Go or chess-like boardgames),
- possibility,
- ability.

Answer (score 0):

I looked in Minjung's English-Korean & Korean-English Dictionary. On page 382 of this palm size dictionary, 1st column, 3/4's of the way down there is a concise explanation of 수 with examples. Here is a snapshot: 《수단. 방법》 a means; a way;a resource, help; a device (방안). End of quote. So in your 2nd sentence, a literal way of asking for help if translated into English would be,"Is there a way (수) you could help me a moment?" Or, "Do you know of a way (수) that you could help me a moment?" In fact, it is legitimate to attach the subject particle 가 to 수 . For example: 잠깐 나 좀 도와줄 수가 있니?